# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in word frequency calculation

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

This is my logic for word frequency. I'm not supposed to use `HashMap` to store the frequency of a word. I am getting an `ArrayIndexoutofBoundsException`, but can't figure out why.

Program:

```
package thirdassignments;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordFreq2 {

    public void Working() {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:/Users/kishansr/Desktop/file1.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
            }
            fileReader.close();

            String sentence = stringBuffer.toString();
            String [] words = sentence.split("\\s+"); // splits by whitespace
            for (String word : words) {
                System.out.println(word);
            }

            String word1[] = new String [100000];
            int count[] = {0}, count1 = 0;
            for (String word : words) {
                count1 = count1 + 1;
            }
            System.out.println("COunt :" + count1);
            for (String word : words) {
                for (int i = 0 ; i < count1 ; i++) {
                    if (word1[i] != word) {
                        word1[i] = word;
                        count[i] = 1; // here the exception is oocuring
                    }

                    else if (word1[i] == word) {
                        count[i] = count[i] + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0 ; i < count1 ; i++) {
                System.out.println(count[i] + " : " + word1[i]);
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WordFreq2 wf = new WordFreq2();
        long startruntime = System.nanoTime();
        wf.Working();
        long endruntime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println( "start time: " + startruntime + " end time :" + endruntime + " diferrence: " + (endruntime - startruntime));
    }

}
```

Output :

> This
>   is
>   the
>   Hewlett
>   Packard
>   company
>   .
>   This
>   Company
>   is
>   spread
>   over
>   the
>   world
>   and
>   has
>   established
>   its
>   footprints
>   in
>   almost
>   all
>   countries
>   .
>   It
>   has
>   a
>   huge
>   employee
>   count
>   and
>   has
>   more
>   women
>   employees
>   than
>   male
>   employees
>   .
>   COunt :39
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: count has a size of one. So you have only an element on index 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've instantiated the `count[]` array with a size of 1. It needs to be at least as large as your array.

Try change this line

```
 String word1[]=new String[100000];
 int count[]={0},count1=0;
 for (String word : words) {
     count1=count1+1;
 }
```

to

```
 String word1[]=new String[100000];
 int count1=0;
 for (String word : words) {
     count1=count1+1;
 }
 count[]= new int[count1];
```

Comment: i thought It will initialize the array with 0 and add elements to it.Did not know that the array size will also get fixed with this initialization..Thanks.

Comment: If that's the way you'd like to go, try using an `ArrayList` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your count array :

```
int count[]={0};
```

has a single element

So you'll get an exception for count[i] for any i>0.

Perhaps you should initialize it to the same length as the `word1` array :

```
int count[]= new int[100000];
```

In addition, replace `word1[i]==word` with `word1[i].equals(word)`.